# The Nikud of the word תמות in the sentence תמות נפשי עם פלישתים

Tags: hebrew, shoftim--book-of

In the Tanach, Shoftim טז Pasuk ל:

> וַיֹּאמֶר שִׁמְשׁוֹן, תָּמוֹת נַפְשִׁי עִם-פְּלִשְׁתִּים, וַיֵּט בְּכֹחַ, וַיִּפֹּל הַבַּיִת עַל-הַסְּרָנִים וְעַל-כָּל-הָעָם אֲשֶׁר-בּוֹ; וַיִּהְיוּ הַמֵּתִים, אֲשֶׁר הֵמִית בְּמוֹתוֹ, רַבִּים, מֵאֲשֶׁר הֵמִית בְּחַיָּיו.

Why is the word תמות (die) is with the nikud תָּמוֹת and not תָּמוּת ?

Comment: See too מִ֤י מָנָה֙ עֲפַ֣ר יַעֲקֹ֔ב וּמִסְפָּ֖ר אֶת־רֹ֣בַע יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל תָּמֹ֤ת נַפְשִׁי֙ מ֣וֹת יְשָׁרִ֔ים וּתְהִ֥י אַחֲרִיתִ֖י כָּמֹֽהוּ

Comment: my knowledge of grammar is limited, but don't they mean different things? Tamut is the statement that "it will be put to death" but "tamot" is a "request that it will be put to death." The Ibn Ezra on Isaiah 53:9 writes that it means "Let me die with the Philistines" (שהיה רוצה שימות עם הגוים)

Answer (score 4):

It's the jussive form of the verb; for more on the form, see [Gesenius §48](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/48). It's used to express a wish ("may it die" as opposed to תָּמוּת  "it will die"); for more on the use of the form, see [Gesenius §109](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/109).